# How to deselect the checkbox after click on it in gwt grid having single selction model

Tags: gwt

I am using GWT Data grid with single selection model and now i want to deselect the check box cell after click on it on some specific condition.

I have override **onBrowserEvent** of **CheckboxCell** and added below line to deselect it.

**selectionModel.setSelected(object, false);**

but i am not able to deselect it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Maybe it is better to add a `SelectionChangeHandler` to your `selectionModel` and change the value of the model-parameter bound to the `CheckboxCell` on the specific condition.

Comment: yes you are right but inside that i have added below line of code **selectionModel.setSelected(object, false);** still not working.

Comment: i think i got it. see my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectionModel.setSelected(object, false);` only deselects the currently selected row.
Add a `FieldUpdater` to the `Column` containing the `CheckboxCell`, in which you reset the value of the checkbox on the specific condition. `datagridTable.redraw()` updates the view.

**Edit:** Looks like `redraw()` doesn't update the value of checkbox. Manually updating the value of `CheckBoxCell` should work. See updated code.

Pseudo-Code:

```
checkboxColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<DataGridObject, Boolean>() {

    @Override
    public void update(int index, DataGridObject object, Boolean value) {
        if(specificCondition) {
            object.setCheckboxValue(false);
            checkboxCell.setViewData(object, false);
            datagridTable.redraw();
        }


    }
});
```

More info: **FieldUpdater example** on http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/DataGrid.html